# How to take screenshot for window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm beginner in Qt/C++ programmation and i want to get screenshot of my window using Qt.

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>


    int main( int argc, char **argv )
    {
        QApplication a( argc, argv );

        QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
        hello.resize( 100, 30 );

        a.setMainWidget( &hello );
        hello.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short way to take a screenshot of a specific window :

```
/* Take a screenshot of a window 
 Notice that window is a: QWidget *window; */

originalPixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(window);
```